# Make vue-cli copy files to few folders right after build

Tags: webpack, vue-cli

I added one more copy directive to the `config.plugin('copy')` module:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin('copy').tap(([pathConfigs]) => {

        pathConfigs.push({
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
            to: path.resolve(__dirname, './../server/web'),
            toType: 'dir'
        })

        return [pathConfigs]
    })

    return config;
}
```

The problem is that this modification causes an error, because vue removes `/build` folder before building the project:

`[copy-webpack-plugin] unable to locate 'D:\test\client\build' at 'D:\test\client\build'
ERROR  Build failed with errors.`

Is there some more trouble-less and convinient way to copy build to more than one dir?

Comment: I have a similar issue. My application is a rails api-only app and where the client consists of just the index.html and assets. I'd like the build to be placed in the public directory. So I set outputDir in vue.config.js to './public'.  I don't get this error if the public directory is missing. But oddly once it's created I get it  every other time I run the build! it's a crazy unexplainable behavior!  What's weirder is if set outputDir to any other path it works fine!  Real head scratcher!

Comment: hyraynaud: public and dist are both official folders used by vue build process. Everything in public is copied without being modified in any way over to the dist folder.